# Configuring SSL for Apache 2.2 on Windows

Tags: windows, apache, tomcat, ssl

I am new to configuring apache and I am trying to configure it to use ssl. Here are my configuration files.

httpd.conf file:
I uncommented the following lines:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

this is my httpd-ssl file:

```
Listen 443

AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl

SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:C:/Program Files/Apache Software    Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

SSLMutex default

##
## SSL Virtual Host Context
##

    <Directory "c:/tracker">
   Order Deny,Allow
   Allow from all
   AllowOverride all
</Directory>

<virtualHost *:443> 
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "C:/keys/myco.biz.cert"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/keys/myco.biz.key"

 ServerName myco.biz
 ServerAlias myco.biz
 ServerAdmin test@test.net
 DirectoryIndex index.cfm index.html index.htm
 DocumentRoot "c:/tracker"
 # here comes the proxy details!!!
 ProxyRequests on    
<proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</proxy>
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8109/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8109/
```

And here is my server.xml file in Tomcat:

```
<Connector port="8180" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />

<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8109 -->
<Connector port="8109" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" enableLookups="false" />
```

With this configuration, I am able to restart apache. But I have no access to my site. I get a unresponsive server error in chrome.

If I take the configuration out of httpd-ssl file and put it in httpd-vhosts and change the port from 443 to port 80. I am able to get to the site. But its not an ssl connection. Any help is really appreciated. I don't have any errors in the error log in apache, or in the windows event viewer.

I have Windows server 2003 R2 running on the server. I also generated my cert and key files using openssl. I don't have any certificate related errors.

Any thoughts or suggestions on what I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: `redirectPort` should be 443, not 8443, and you don't need the HTTP connectors at all with Apache HTTPD in front, or the <Directory> entry either as you are proxy-passing /, but this is off-topic, belongs on server-fault.